# amazon EC2 tomcat start looks like success, but cannot access port 8080 page

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

In the morning I try with EC2, create the AMI, uploading the war file to the machine, all went perfect. Then I use iptables to make the url works on port 80, that goes through well.

Then I update the war file from my local and thn upload to EC2, and try to restart the server, everything is not working.. (not even with port 8080 to bring up the default tomcat page) and in my catalina.out log I saw:
'''

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 1 more
```

'''
I am pretty sure the tomcat-juli.jar is exists, and it is under lib folder, how can I solve this issue?

I am using Tomcat 7, and EC2 also using Tomcat 7 with java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact the amazon support already and issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

It's a tomcat 8 ? , Could you have a conflict of versions with your ./WEB-INF/lib & $CATALINA_HOME/lib libraries ?

Comment: It is tomcat7, and in EC2 I only install tomcat7 with java 7 only